# <form action="/sampleServlet" giving me exception

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

In my jsp  if I call `<form action="/sampleServlet" method="get" name="form1">`, I get the following exception :

> http 404 error--sampleServlet is not found.I set sampleServlet in
>   web.xml file and  url-pattern also set to /sampleServlet.

Why I am getting 404 (not found servlet.)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you are using URL in HTML, without leading / they are relative to the current URL (ie current page displayed). With leading / they are relative to the website root :

```
<form action="/context-path/sampleServlet">
```

or

```
<form action="sampleServlet">
```

will do what you want.

I suggest you to add the context inside the action path dynamically. 
Example (in JSP) :

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sampleServlet">
```

With this you will never have to change the path, for example, if you move your file or copy your code, or rename your context!

Comment: This is giving me a 404 error with the following URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/fileUpload

Comment: @advocate You can't use this URL directly into the browser, the `${}` content should be rendered by the server before. Also, the port is not common, is your server really running on your computer on port 8888 ? You are better to post a new question if your setup is different of the OP.

Comment: I didn't type directly into the browser, that's what I ended up with after taking the link. I believe the issue was I pasted that into an HTML file and I needed to paste it into a .JSP file.

Comment: @advocate sure, the file extension will be filtered by the server to know if it need to process it or not.

Comment: as a side remark, an URL starting with a slash isn't absolute as such, it is relative, but relative to the site root.

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes you are right, an absolute URL will include the protocol and domain name, i'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

might help you

**servlet configuration**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.sampleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sampleServlet/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet Code :**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class sampleServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 
    }
}
```

**JSP code :**

```
<html>
  <body>
     <form action="/sampleServlet/" method="GET">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit form "/>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can click on submit button and after you can see servlet out put

Answer (score 0):

Just use  action="sampleServlet"

It will work for you.