# HTTP Status 404 Servlet-The requested resource is not available

Tags: servlets

I am making one simple program to take few fields as input and then after clicking on confirm button confirm.jsp will appear.

I have created Controller.java servlet to identify the button clicked and then open the jsp. 
Controller.java is stored in directory WEB-INF/classes/ch2/servletController and submit.jsp,register.jsp,confirm.jsp are stored in /ch2/servletController directory.

Whenever i click on confirm button, i get below error. WebApplication is the name of my project. I am using netBeans IDE.

HTTP Status 404 - /WebApplication/ch2/servletController/Controller

type Status report

message /WebApplication/ch2/servletController/Controller

description The requested resource is not available.

Please find below web.xml,servlet and all the jsp files..

**register.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">  
<title>Register</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form method="get" action="Controller">  
<p><b>E-store</b></p>  
<br>  
<br>  
<p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="${param.FirstName}"></p>  
<p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="${param.LastName}"></p>  
<p>Enter Mail-id: <input type="text" name="MailId" value="${param.MailId}"></p>  
<p>Enter PhoneNo: <input type="text" name="PhoneNo" value="${param.PhoneNo}"></p>  
<p><input type="submit" name="confirmButton" value="confirm"></p>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**confirm.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">  
<title>Confirm Details</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form method="get" action="Controller" >  
<p><b>E-store</b></p>  
<br>  
<br>  
<p>First Name: ${param.FirstName}<input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value="${param.FirstName}"></input></p>  
<p>Last Name: ${param.LastName}<input type="hidden" name="LastName" value="${param.LastName}"></input></p>  
<p>Mail-id: ${param.MailId}<input type="hidden" name="MailId" value="${param.MailId}"></input></p>  
<p>PhoneNo: ${param.PhoneNo}<input type="hidden" name="PhoneNo" value="${param.PhoneNo}"></input></p>  
<input type="submit" name="EditButton" value="Edit">  
<input type="submit" name="Submitbutton" value="Submit">  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**submit.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">  
<title>Confirm Details</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form>  
<p><b>E-store</b></p>  
<br>  
<br>  
<p>Thank You for the registration. Your details have been submitted as follows-</p>  
<p>First Name: ${param.FirstName}<input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value="${param.FirstName}"></input></p>  
<p>Last Name: ${param.LastName}<input type="hidden" name="LastName" value="${param.LastName}"></input></p>  
<p>Mail-id: ${param.MailId}<input type="hidden" name="MailId" value="${param.MailId}"></input></p>  
<p>PhoneNo: ${param.PhoneNo}<input type="hidden" name="PhoneNo" value="${param.PhoneNo}"></input></p>  

</form>  

</body>  
</html>
```

**Controller.java**

```
package ch2.servletController;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
public class Controller extends HttpServlet  
{  
        @Override  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException  
    {  
        String address=null;  
        if(request.getParameter("confirmButton")!= null)  
        {  
            address="confirm.jsp";  
        }  
        else if(request.getParameter("EditButton")!= null)  
        {  
            address="register.jsp";  
        }  
        else if(request.getParameter("Submitbutton")!=null)  
        {  
            address="submit.jsp";  
        }  
        RequestDispatcher Dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher(address);  
        Dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
    }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>FirstController</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>ch2.servletController.Controller</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>FirstController</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <session-config>  
        <session-timeout>  
            30  
        </session-timeout>  
    </session-config>  
    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">  
<title>First JSP</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form>  
<p><b>Welcome to E-store</b></p>  
<br>  
<br>  
<p>Click to <a href="ch2/servletController/register.jsp">Register</a></p>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does your war file deployed have the Controller class?

Comment: 404 error is mostly related to path, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16683950/354831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the location of `register.jsp` to web directory where `index.jsp` is located and it worked for me.