# tomcat server is not loading web.xml it's running jsp's not servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have deployed Java Web application via cpanel on a live server running tomcat 7.0,  it's working fine with .jsp pages. it seems it's  not loading web.xml file so it doesn't map servlets.

I have fully tested my application on local.
Here is  Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>



     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProcessLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>authentication.ProcessLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProcessLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is login.jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login Here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="height:85%">
            <div class="contents"> 

                   <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post"  action="Welcome" >
                    User Name: <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" required  class="txtfield"> <br />
                    Password:<input type="password" size="50" name="txtPass" required  class="txtfield" /> <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" /> 

                    </form>


            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="footer">
            ....
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Student Management</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="library/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container"  style="height:84%">

            <div class="contents" style="margin:0 auto; width:650px">
                Welcome dear:
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

AND Here is my "ProcessLogin" servlet..

```
package authentication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import utilities.User;


@WebServlet(name = "ProcessLogin", urlPatterns = {"/Welcome"})
public class ProcessLogin extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            User user = new User();
            String userName = request.getParameter("txtName");
            String password = request.getParameter("txtPass");
            boolean isUser = user.checkUser(userName,password);


                if (isUser) {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                        session.setAttribute("userId", userName);

                        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                        rd.forward(request, response);

                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?err=1");
                }


        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }



}
```

i have spent dozen's of hour while searching for this issue but i couldn't find solution.

Comment: web.xml is loading properly because JSP files are executed. You don't need to declare servlet in web.xml since you are using annotations and declaring Servlet 3.0 in web.xml, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: When you are submitting, is the context path changed in the URL of the browser? Example : http://localhost:8080/myapp/page.jsp > http://localhost:8080/Welcome ?

Comment: Yes in localhost it working fine and contextPath change but it's not working online

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception/16683950#16683950

Comment: still there context path is change but it can't find the file.

Comment: localhost:8080/myapp/page.jsp > localhost:8080/myapp/Welcome

Comment: Have you tried to remove declaration from web.xml?

Comment: Yes i have tried both way. removing declaration from web.xml and adding annotation. and also removing annotation and adding web.xml declaration

Comment: Url-Pattern says `/Welcome` and action on form just `Welcome`. Maybe try adding the `/` in the action.

Comment: @developerwjk Adding the / will bypass the context-path and for sure not work.

Comment: I think you may be confused as to what a context-path is.

Comment: there was problem with java hosting thank all...