# JSP Servelet 404 Exception Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a java servelet which is also mapped in web.xml file but when i run it it raises 404 error. Here is my source Code
My Form with action is shown below

```
<form name="productsForm" method="post" action="/Checkout">
```

Here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AP Assignment 5</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>Called to process any forms on the website</description>
    <display-name>Form Processing Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Checkout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Checkout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Checkout</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Here is my project hierarchy with my servelet code

[image]

Comment: Any Guess why this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.class` from `<servlet-class>` that is invalid here.

---

It should  be

```
<servlet-class>Servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
```

instead of

```
<servlet-class>Servlets/MyServlet.class</servlet-class>
```

---

--EDIT--

try with appending **Context Path** if you are using it in JSP or append context path directly if using it in HTML.

```
<form name="productsForm" method="post" 
                          action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Checkout">
```

instead of

```
<form name="productsForm" method="post" action="/Checkout">
```

Please have a look at similar issue [form action=“/sampleServlet” giving me exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception).

Comment: What the hell? **Don't forget to add comments.** Don't be lazy.

Comment: I know by mistaken I have placed / in my suggestion but I can correct it. at some point I am correct not completely.

Comment: put `<welcome-file-list>` in the end after `<servlet-mapping>` . It may work.

Comment: @user1375948 did you remove .class extension and removed /

Comment: @JqueryLearner Your profile says : **I believe Cowards and Downvoters without a comment are same.** Nice line.

Comment: @JqueryLearner Don't worry, I will not do anything. :)

Comment: I have updated Web.xml File as you described but its not working sam e404 error saying >>> "HTTP Status 404 - /Checkout"

Comment: you missed `</welcome-file-list>` but I have edited it again.

Comment: @user1375948 please have a look at my updated post. It might help you.

Comment: Now You Found The Gist Of the problem +1. Best Answer 
I Don't know who decrease it to -2 i have not done it anyway now -1 as i added +1

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 mistakes in your web.xml

1. you should not use `.class`
2. if a class is present inside a package then you should use dot(`.`)
   not slash(`/`)

so change

```
<servlet-class>Servlets/MyServlet.class</servlet-class>
```

to

```
<servlet-class>Servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: @Braj yes this is the answer

Comment: Not Working Still 404 Error

Comment: I have eupdated the web.xml file now check whats wrong

Comment: Anyone tell me whats the problem here

Comment: @Braj yes true,but your answer was also half true.You should not have deleted

Comment: @user1375948 try changing the servlet name,if you still get the error then show the folder structure

Comment: @Braj you got -2 may be for your old answer but you have also updated it.

Comment: @JQueryListener why i get -1 is there anything wrong i asked?
also i have shown my project hierarchy in question please check it as renaming servelet won't works

Answer (score 0):

according to my point of view there are no errors on web.xml as well as servelet page.
web.xml should be

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServeletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Package.ServeletName</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServeletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServeletName</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```