# Can't execute servlet from JSP but can access from direct URL (mvc mysql tomcat)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a simple login app using mvc (JSP pages + servlets, running on Apache Tomcat server in Eclipse + Mysql database).

When I access my servlet from the direct URL:

```
http://localhost:8181/stage/LoginControlerdo
```

The servlet's instructions get executed, but do not when the servlet is invoked from the JSP form, it shows a blank page instead.

(Servlet's instructions are just simple messages that show up when the servlet is accessed directly of after actualising the page but not when called from the JSP form).

As you can see I'm using port 8181; I don't think the problem has anything to do with the web.xml config since the server starts correctly but here is a copy

**Web.xml :**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginContro</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>attakmili.com.LoginControler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginContro</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginControlerdo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If anyone has an idea about what's going on I would be grateful.

The JSP code:

```
<form action="LoginControlerdo"  method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Pseudo</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="pseudo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mot De Passe</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you accessing it from the JSP ?? From the Browser Network Tab you can find out whats the issue ??

Comment: Please show you JSP code.

Comment: Edited : Added the JSP Code

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception

Comment: Can you post your servlet code?

Comment: Thank you Preethi Jain, David and Jaydee for the help much appreciated. (Solved, doPost() not doGet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `POST` method to submit your form, but when you access the servlet from browser directly `GET` method will be used.

You have to use the `HttpServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` to implement you logic.

Comment: That was it, that solved it thank you very much.
(Copied the instructions from doGet() to doPost ())

Answer (score 0):

This should work , (Add a slash before LoginControlerdo)

```
<form action="/LoginControlerdo"  method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Pseudo</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="pseudo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mot De Passe</td>
<td><input type="text"  name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</form>
```