# How to pass form input value from jsp page to java class?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, inputbox

I've set up a dynamic web project using Eclipse EE and added a jsp page.

The page is set as the welcome page when the project is run on a server and shows an input box along with a submit button.

My question is how can I pass the value entered into the input box to my HelloServlet class on button click?

Does anyone have any advice on how I could about this?

The hello jsp page layout is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Fibonacci Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="HelloServlet">            
             <b>Fibonacci Sequence Length </b>  <br>
             <input type="text" name="fibNum"size="20px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px" >

        </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the servlet class set up which extends HttpServlet:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    int fibNum;

    //parse input from hello.jsp input box 
    //and assign to fibNum variable


}
```

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/handling-html-form-data-with-java-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a the http method in your html form as ['GET' or 'POST'](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp). I would set it to 'POST'. Then in your servlet class implement the [doPost() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). 
The method signature will be like below;

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

You would be able to retrieve the parameters from the `req` object([ServletRequest class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)) using the methods like

```
getParameter(java.lang.String name) 
getParameterMap()
```

Read the linked javadoc to see the methods available to retrieve the parameters.

In your case you could extract the parameters like;

```
String fibNum = req.getParameter("fibNum");
```

You could use `Integer.valueOf(fibNum)` to convert to integer if you want.

Comment: Okay I've followed the above steps and implemented the doPost() method. Can you elaborate as to how the input value is extracted from the jsp page in this method?

Comment: So it would be like this:     ` String username = req.getParameter("fibNum"); System.out.println("username: " + username);`When I click the submit button on the `hello` page to pass the value, the page shows `the requested resource is not available`

Comment: See if this answer helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception