# 404 not found error for servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have embedded `department.jsp` in `create.jsp`. My `department.jsp` has a table in which i submit data, the action is on a servlet but on submitting it is giving a 404 error for servlet.

`create.jsp` in body-

```
<header>     
        <img style="text-align:left" src="images.png" width="200" height="100" alt="NSIC-logo1"/> 

        <h1>File Tracking System</h1>

        <form style="float:right;" action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
        </form>                       
        <br>            
    </header>
    <a href="department.jsp" target="frame2">Create</a>
    <iframe style="height:530px;width:1340px  " src="department.jsp" name="frame2">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
```

`department.jsp` in body-

```
<form action="DepartmentServlet" method="post">
            <center>                
            <table id="depart">  
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Create Department</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Company Name :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="company" value="" size="50"    /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Department Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="department" value="" size="50" />  </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Head Office :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="place" value="" size="50"   /></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
        </form>
```

`DepartmentServlet.java`

```
public class DepartmentServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
            System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    }       
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("admin="+session.getAttribute("admin"));
   if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("admin") != null){
               String admin=(String)session.getAttribute("admin"); 
                boolean status=false;
    try{
        String department=request.getParameter("department");
        String company=request.getParameter("company");
        String place=request.getParameter("place");
        boolean checkd=dcheck.value(department);
        boolean checkc=checkchar.value(company);
        boolean checkp=checkchar.value(place);
        if(checkd==true&&checkc==true&&checkp==true) {
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="insert into department(departmentname,company,place) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1,department); 
        pstmt.setString(2,company);
        pstmt.setString(3,place);
        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}

            if(status){
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("values have been inserted,"+admin);
                  response.sendRedirect("insert.jsp");
                        }
              else 
              {   
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("failed to insert");
                  response.sendRedirect("notinsert.jsp");
              }
            }
        else{response.sendRedirect("entry.jsp");}
            }catch(SQLException e){}  
              }else{
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
    rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: use `<jsp:include`

Comment: Sir do you want me to include `DepartmentServlet` in my `department.jsp` page but isn't  `<jsp:include` used to include only jsp

Comment: No I am suggesting that you include `department.jsp`  Servlets are not included, the are GET'd or POST'd

Comment: Sir can you please give a small example something similar to my case

Comment: can you plz share your output also.

Comment: Please check the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception). It might help you.

Comment: where is your department.jsp is located in your project ? In IFRAME src you should give path of jsp from WEB-INF folder.

Comment: In the first part of image the table which you can see is in `department.jsp` so the path in iframe should be correcrt only when i submit does the 404 error page displays.                                                                                       `project name`->`Web Pages`->`WEB-INF`->web.xml                                         .                          `Web Pages` ->`jsp/html files`   (not in WEB-INF)