# Spring MVC - When I am click on Submit button on jsp (Post request) my URL changed and my work flow not coming into controller class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I am click on Submit button on jsp (Post request) my URL changed and my work flow not coming into controller class

First time when I hit URL http://localhost:9080/LaunchingGateway_Maintance/services/Test
my jsp will be opend but when I click on Vendor button on jsp URL will changed to http://localhost:9080/validate and my flow not comming to my controller and on browser I got The webpage cannot be found

please help me I am stuck here from last two week.

my Controller class is : -

```
package com.us.launchingGatewayController;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.us.bean.SSOConfigDynaFldsSrveLstBean;
import com.us.validator.SSOconfigValidator;

@Controller
public class LaunchingGatewayController {


    @Autowired
    SSOConfigDynaFldsSrveLstBean SSOConfigDynaFldsSrveLstBean;

    @Autowired
    ModelAndView modelNView;

    @Autowired
    SSOconfigValidator SSOConfigValidator;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/Test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse resp)throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test In test");
        modelNView.setViewName("test");

        return modelNView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("hi");
        return "test";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView validate(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("Test In Validate");
        SSOConfigValidator.validateSSOconfig(SSOConfigDynaFldsSrveLstBean);
        modelNView.setViewName("test");
        return modelNView;


    }


}



my jsp is :-

<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Launching Gateway Maintenance</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">   
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor='#E8E8E8'>

    <h1 align="center">Launching Gateway Maintenance</h1>

    <form  method="POST" action="/validate">
        <center>



            <input type="submit" name="validate" value="Vendor" /> 

        </center>



    </form>


</body>
</html>




my web.xml is :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">    
    <display-name>LaunchingGateway_Maintance</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
              <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>


my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml is :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.us.launchingGatewayController" />
    <bean id="ssoConfigValidator" class="com.us.validator.SSOconfigValidator"></bean>

    <bean id="modelNView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView"></bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="../jsp/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with you context path. According to form you submitting, try this:

```
<FORM ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/validate">
```

Compare this two urls :

```
http://localhost:9080/LaunchingGateway_Maintance/services/Test
```

and

```
http://localhost:9080/validate
```

So looks like you are missing some context path *LaunchingGateway_Maintance*

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception) post as well