# description The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am receiving error while trying to run the code.
Not able to find where is the problem.
I may missing some minor details, it will be great if you could correct it.

CalculateServlet

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    @WebServlet(name="CalculateServlet", urlPatterns={"/CalculateServlet"})
    public class CalculateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public CalculateServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //assuming request as the object of the HttpServletRequest Class.
    //retrieving & storing the values from the textboxes into the String Variables.
    String n1 = request.getParameter("fnum");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(n1); //Converting String into Integer Variable
    String n2 = request.getParameter("snum");
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(n2); int ans=0;

    //performing calculation according to the selection made from the Radio Buttons named "calc".
    if(request.getParameter("calc").equals("Add"))
    ans = num1+num2;
    if(request.getParameter("calc").equals("Sub"))
    ans = num1-num2;
    if(request.getParameter("calc").equals("Div"))
    ans = num1/num2;
    if(request.getParameter("calc").equals("Multi"))
    ans = num1*num2;

    //assuming response as the object of the HttpServletResponse Class.
    //displaying output to the user 
    response.getWriter().println(ans); 

    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}}
```

Index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="CalculateServlet">
   <input type="text" name="fnum"/>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" name="snum"/>
   <br/>
   Select Operation
   <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="calc" value="Add"/>Add
   <input type="radio" name="calc" value="Sub"/>Subtract
   <input type="radio" name="calc" value="Div"/>Divide
   <input type="radio" name="calc" value="Multi"/>Multiply
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit"/>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPM8k.png)

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rDql.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL Pattern in your `web.xml` is

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CalculateServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CalculateServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But your jsp submits it to "calculate"

```
<form action="calculate">
```

Change it to,

```
<form action="CalculateServlet">
```

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested but still with no success

Comment: @onkarpatil. what is the URL you are seeing in the browser after you click submit?

Comment: @onkarpatil. Can you also provide the error you are seeing.

Comment: @onkarpatil. This does'nt seem right, Even after changing the form action to CalculateServlet, the URL still directs to /Calc/calculation.
Can you rebuild and re-deploy?

Comment: Sure i will try

Comment: Still with the same Error
http://localhost:8080/Calc/calculation?fnum=1&snum=2&calc=Add&submit=Calculate
HTTP Status 404 - /Calc/calculation
type Status report

message /Calc/calculation

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/8.0.38

Comment: Can you have a look at directory structure

Comment: @onkarpatil. the directory structure looks fine.  This still does not seem right.  Can you update the jsp file with the changes in the question.

Comment: I closed the work space and reopened and now it works fine. Thanks Jerin Joseph for your time and immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are close.

Take a look at this thread:

[<form action="/sampleServlet" giving me exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception)

I think your issue is the form action is set to **calculation**